# How to set up a delegate to a class without the use of prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, iphone, delegation

I have two classes I would like them to speak with each other. Class A contains a tableView and when users hitting a table row, I fire my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. In this method I need to inform class B about this through a delegate. I know how delegates work but having a hard time to figure how to set the delegate of A without using the prepareForSegue method.

Normally I would do this when I set up my delegate

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goToManipulator"]) {
        ManipulatorViewController *secondVC = (ManipulatorViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        [secondVC setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

But how can I set the delegate without the use of prepareForSegue?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT :**

This is how the structure of my storyboard looks like. The "receiver" viewcontroller is the one that will get the data and display in the "current name" label depending on what's been selected in the tableview from the "sender" viewcontroller, closest to the right.

http://oi62.tinypic.com/2li99w1.jpg

Comment: You mean you aren't using a segue to create the new controller? How are you creating it then?

Comment: Do you want to use coding only?

Comment: How do you want to create `secondVC`? From xib, from storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: I should have explained it better, but please look at the edit I have made. And yes I believe I need to use some sort of segue to create new viewcontrollers. :)

Comment: @All : What if my destination VC is not UIViewController Class. Like In my case its UIPageViewConroller and I cant use prepare for Segue as its looking for destination as UIViewController

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ManipulatorViewController *secondVC = [[ManipulatorViewController alloc] init...];
    [secondVC setDelegate:self];

    //if you use push transition in UINavigationController
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];

    //if you use modal transition
    [self presentViewController:secondVC animated:YES completion:nil]
}
```

`init...` means that initialization depends on your program architecture.

**EDIT**

If you want to get `secondVC` from storyboard, use

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    ManipulatorViewController* secondVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondVC"];
```

And don't forget to add identifier for your viewController in storyboard.

Comment: If you do not want to use the prepare for segue method (I don't know why you would not) You need to push the VC onto the stack like Valentin does above. However, note that you may also initialize the `ManipulatorViewController` through the storyboard instead of `alloc` and `init`. This is the only other way you will get a reference to the new view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your use case like this:

In the Receiver, you open the Sender. There you select a value, and after selecting the value you want to tell the Receiver about the new value.

You can create a protocol on Sender, that Receiver implements. Then, in the function that catches the chosen value in Sender, you call the protocol method (e.g. didSelectNewName() or something).

Of course, you need a handle to the Receiver, which you typically get via the delegate. But wether you use a segue or other method to transition from Receiver to Sender, you will all the same have the opportunity to set the delegate of the Sender.

If this is not what you are looking for, please explain exactly how you initialize the Sender, and why segue is not desirable.

Comment: So far I have a protocol on the "sender", and I have made my "receiver" implementing this protocol together with the one required method. I just can't find a way to set the delegate of the sender "id <LabelChangeTextDelegate> delegate;" with the storyboard structure I have used. I'm still open for using segue, but then, you might could tell me how I can solve this puzzle? :)

Comment: I see on your storyboard that you have linked them together as a Storyboard Embed Segue. That means you can (should) use a segue to transition to the Sender. So I'm not sure I understand your problem...?

Answer (score 0):

Is View Controller B already instantiated when A's cells are tapped? If it is and you're not using prepareForSegue to get the other View Controller's identity, it might be better to use NSNotification Center. In View Controller A's didSelectRowAtIndex method, you can put

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"yourNotificationName" object:nil userInfo:dictionaryWithYourData];
```

and it will put up a notification to your whole app that the row was selected. If you initialize a dictionary with any info you want before hand, it can be passed through userInfo. Then, in View Controller B's viewDidLoad, add

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourMethod:) name:@"yourNotificationName" object:nil];
```

to make it listen for the notification. The selector you set will accept the NSNotification as a parameter, so you can get the dictionary as follows:

```
- (void)yourMethod:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *yourData = [notification userInfo];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do.

In the .m file:

```
@implementation ViewController{

   SecondViewController *svc;

}
```

And then below you need to an action like this:

```
- (IBAction)goToView2:(id)sender {
    if (!svc) {
        svc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"];
        [svc setDelegate:self];
    }
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
}
```

Just make sure to set the correct identifier in the StoryBoard to the ViewController where protocol is declared.